# Objectify : Use an entity key juste created

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I have a question and I didn't find what I wanted to do. I'm using google Endpoints with appengine and Objectify. I have an entity Round which need the key of an entity Game just created. So when I have to create a new Game I create my new game and after that I create the round with the new key. I use the function .now() to save the game but sometimes the game is not created and I have a Round created without any Game. Because it was problematic I decided to loop to get the game until it's created, but I know it's a very bad way to do it and I am wondering what I can use instead.

Before :

```
//Create a new game
Game game = new Game(pending_game.getPlayer(),pending_game.getApplicant());
ofy().save().entity(game).now();

//Get the player just created
game = ofy().load().type(Game.class).filter("player1 =", pending_game.getPlayer()).filter("player2 =", pending_game.getApplicant()).first().now();
Key<Game> key_game = Key.create(Game.class, game.getId());          
//We add the new round
Round round = new Round(key_game,generateWord());
ofy().save().entity(round).now();
```

Now :

```
//Create a new game
Game game = new Game(pending_game.getPlayer(),pending_game.getApplicant());
ofy().save().entity(game).now();

Key<Game> key_game = null;
//Get the player just created 
for(int i=0; i<5 && key_game == null;i++)
{
    //Get the key of the new game created
    game = ofy().load().type(Game.class).filter("player1 =", pending_game.getPlayer()).filter("player2 =", pending_game.getApplicant()).first().now();
    key_game = Key.create(Game.class, game.getId());
}                   
//We add the new round
Round round = new Round(key_game,generateWord());
ofy().save().entity(round).now();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, the reason you are seeing the behavior that you are is because the query is eventually consistent. Each loop is actually re-saving the entity; the loop is just going until the query indexes catch up. Needless to say, this is a bad approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why load the saved `game`?

```
Game game = new Game(pending_game.getPlayer(),pending_game.getApplicant());
ofy().save().entity(game).now();    
Key<Game> key_game = Key.create(Game.class, game.getId());          
//We add the new round
Round round = new Round(key_game,generateWord());
ofy().save().entity(round).now();
```

If your intention was to make sure that saving the game was successful before moving on, [use a transaction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_Using_transactions):

> Either all of the operations in the transaction are applied, or none of them are applied.

[Objectify transaction docs](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Transactions) with examples.

Comment: I thought to use transaction but the issue is that I can't use parameters from my function if there are not finals. What can I do ? Declare a final copy of each of this parameters ?

Comment: There's no need to create a copy. Just add the `final` keyword to the parameters when you declare the method. For example, `public Article setArticleTags(@Named("url") final String url)`

Comment: Thanks for your help it's working fine. Just one more thing. I have to register a Player with a pseudo and I want the pseudo to be unique. So when I want to add a player I check if the pseudo is not already taken. But if 2 people take the same pseudo at almost the same time it's working. Do you know how I can avoid it ?

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to make the pseudo the entity's `@id`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546456/google-app-engine-how-to-handle-concurrency-racing-condition) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645582/in-google-app-engine-how-do-i-avoid-creating-duplicate-entities-with-the-same-a) [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750287/how-to-prevent-race-conditions-in-google-app-engine-using-java?rq=1) relevant links.